# Wordpress redirect from URL with BuddyPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, buddypress

I am using the plugin BuddyPress on my WordPress site and when the user clicks on their profile they are redirected to the URL "/members/USERNAME/profile/home/". However, I do not want this page to be there and so I would like the profile 'landing' page to be the URL "/members/USERNAME/activity/".

I am not experienced with WordPress or PHP but I attempted to code a redirect for this when the user ends up on the 'home' page which is placed within my BuddyPress members/single/home.php file within my child theme:

```
$redirect_url_home = get_home_url();
$redirect_url_home_tt = $redirect_url_home;
$username_redirect_tt = wp_get_current_user();
$new_redirect_slug = "'/members/'.$username_redirect_tt->user_login.'/activity/'";
$redirect_url_home_tt. = $new_redirect_slug;
echo($redirect_url_home_tt);
wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url_home_tt );
```

This code doesn't work but that was my thinking of how to solve my problem and I'm sure there is an easier/nicer way to do what I would like, maybe even without a coded redirect and within BuddyPress itself? I have tried using their forum/documentation for answers but haven't had a reply or found anything useful.

As I say I have no experience with this sort of stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, to add, I cannot link the site as it is currently on a localhost.

Thanks!

This question was originally posted on StackExchange here (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/386414/wordpress-redirect-from-url-with-buddypress) but I have had no reply as of yet and I would really like one so hopefully, this reaches someone that can help!

Comment: I build a lot of WordPress sites, and although you could do this in code, I'd personally recommend using a plugin such as [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). Very friendly GUI and you could easily add a mapping between the two

Comment: Hi, @ChrisHaas thank you for your reply, I have seen this plugin but wasn't sure if it worked with a local host, as I don't have a set URL to redirect the user to so I thought that adding it in code by the use of "get_home_url()" would be better. I will give it a go now though and see if it gets me anywhere!

Comment: The target URL can definitely **not** include the host and protocol, and instead just be an absolute path like `/home/xyz`. What's nice about that plugin is that you don't have to really worry about WordPress and BuddyPress anymore, you are just dealing with HTTP and paths, so you can reason about things at a higher level.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks for your recommendation, I have managed to get it all working correctly!